How to register a custom ITraceListener in SpecFlow 3.9.74
We are upgrading from specflow 1.something to version 3.9.74. I'm having some trouble getting our custom TraceListener to work.
This is the code of the IRuntimePlugin:
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Plugins;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Tracing;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider;

[assembly: RuntimePlugin(typeof(SpecFlowTracerPlugin.SpecFlowTracerPlugin))]

namespace SpecFlowTracerPlugin
{
    public class SpecFlowTracerPlugin : IRuntimePlugin
    {
        public void Initialize(RuntimePluginEvents runtimePluginEvents, RuntimePluginParameters runtimePluginParameters, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration)
        {
            runtimePluginEvents.CustomizeTestThreadDependencies +=
                (sender, args) => { args.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<SpecFlowTracer, ITraceListener>(); };
        }
    }
}


This is the code of the TraceListener class (it uses our own tracing framework, filters out some noise, and ensures that the test output is written to the output while test is running, not only at the end):
    
public class SpecFlowTracer : ITraceListener
    {
        private readonly Trace _trace = new Trace("SpecFlow", "TestStep");

        public void WriteTestOutput(string message) => Trace(message);

        public void WriteToolOutput(string message) => Trace(message);

        private void Trace(string message)
        {
            if (message.StartsWith("done: ")) return;
            var context = FeatureContext.Current;
            if (context != null)
            {
                message = $"{DateTime.Now:yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\t{context.FeatureInfo.Title}: {message}";
            }
            _trace.TraceInfo($"-> {message}");
            // Next line is required to show progress while test is running
            TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(message);
            // Next line is required to show output in xml and other places
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

Both classes are defined in a class library that is used as a plugin by the main test project. In our specflow test project, the class library is is included as a reference. In the app.config file of the test project there used to be this code:
<specflow>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <add name="SpecFlowTracer" path="." type="Runtime" />
    </plugins>
</specFlow>

However, this is no longer needed in specflow 3 according to the documentation (it doesn't even compile). Instead, plugins are detected automatically when their dll is present in the bin directory of the test project.
And indeed, when running a test with the debugger attached, I can see that the Initialize method is called correctly, but the constructor of the SpecFlowTracer class is never called (I checked by adding an empty default constructor with a breakpoint in it). It appears that the default implementation is still used.
I've also tried registering it using the following code in the IRuntimePlugin's Initialize method:
public void Initialize(RuntimePluginEvents runtimePluginEvents, RuntimePluginParameters runtimePluginParameters, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration)
{
    runtimePluginEvents.RegisterGlobalDependencies += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<SpecFlowTracer, ITraceListener>();
    };
}

But that results in an exception being thrown:
BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'An object has been resolved for this interface already.'
Update: I've tried the same with CustomizeGlobalDependencies instead of RegisterGlobalDependencies, but the same exception is throw.
When I inspect the registrations property of the objectContainer, I can see that there is indeed an existing registration for ITraceListener: the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Tracing.DefaultTraceListener.
What is the correct way to register a tracelistener?

I think we need to see a lot more code than this. Do you have any hooks? How are your tests initialized?

Apologies, I have edited the question. In the main test project we have lot's of specflow hooks as well as [OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown] methods for the NUnit test runner. None of these methods mention the tracer plugin.

Which .NET Framework version are you using? Newer versions of SpecFlow use SpecFlow.json, not app.config.

We use .NET 4.8. We use SpecFlow.json, although app.config is still allowed as well. The plugin is not mentioned in specflow.json, because there is no way to do so.

The SpecFlow docs mention runtime plugin events. One of them is called "RegisterGlobalDependencies" and I wonder if that might the missing piece.

As I stated in my question, I already tried RegisterGlobalDependencies, which resulted in a Bodi.ObjectContainerException.

Just updated my question. I tried the same with CustomizeGlobalDependencies, but the same exception is thrown.

This appears to be similar to an open issue: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1590

What about adding this other assembly as an external step binding assembly?

I could give it a try, but I don't expect that will change anything because the Initialize method is called as expected, which indicates that the plugin is found and used correctly. The only thing that doesn't work is the registration of the tracelistener...

This also appears to be related: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1876
